# Meaning of “Schenk mir noch mal ein”

Tags: translation, meaning, german-to-english, lyrics

I’m trying to understand the lyrics of *Es ist wie es ist* by Böhse Onkelz, where at some point it says:

> Ich will wissen wie der Tod schmeckt,
>   und schenk mir noch mal ein.

My understanding is:

> I want to know how death tastes, and serve me one more time.

I’m thinking at this *serve* as *put me in the game* or *get in the game,* like living life as fully as possible, or something like that. Is this even close to the real meaning of that second line?

Comment: Likely not an imperative (as the question suggests) but parallel to _will_.

Comment: @chirlu Yes, I've been somewhat unclear, that "serve" was related to "will", I didn't want to repeat "I want to know", but now I'm wondering if it's even correct to omit it (I'm not a native English speaker :)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ich (will wissen, wie der Tod schmeckt, und) schenk mir noch mal ein

can be translated as

> I want to know what death tastes like, and (I) pour myself another cup/glass

Comment: I think it is important to explain that "death" is equal to "alcohol" here, because the song is about alcoholism. See answer of @Jens Krüger

Comment: You may be right there, but at least the title of the OP suggests that this is not what he was asking.

Answer (score 10):

In the context of the song the meaning is literal.
He wants to drink another drink.

> Ich will wissen, wie der Tod schmeckt,
>   und schenk mir noch mal ein.

And he is serving himself. The translation is:

> I want to know what death tastes like
>   and pour (a drink) for me once again.

In my understanding the song is about alcoholism:

> Und ich weiß
>   Schnaps und der Teufel sind eins

Even though he knows the drink is the devil he still wants more.